# How to run BurpSuite behind a proxy?

Tags: proxy

I am testing a web application by using BurpSuite Intruder, after several bruteforce attempts, I get locked out for flooding.

Is there a way to make the BurpSuite Intruder requests run through a proxy, so that I can continue with my work?

EDIT:
I managed to change the IP for Burp Suite with software called UltraSurf, this is a windows application and routes ALL traffic on the computer to the proxy. 
However, it is not exactly a clean option, sometimes it fails me, and I am on Linux now.

What are other, cleaner options, perhaps proxychains?

Ideally, I'd want something that allows me to change(mask) my external IP quickly and easily, on the fly, during a Burp Suite assessment.
Is it possible?

EDIT2: 
The closest answer to my own question is a VPN.

Comment: Have you referred to product documentation for IP exceptions, etc.?

Comment: @PimpJuiceIT I have googled for solutions, accessed portswigger's documentation on Burp Suite, and haven;t found anything useful.